# Monadic Fold in Constant Space

Tags: performance, haskell

How can I fold a lazy list using a monadic action in constant space? The problem I'm trying to solve is aggregating a large file, and I believe for the sake of performance I require mutability. I have an implementation working in ST using mutable vectors, but it uses too much memory. Below is an example of what I'm attempting. I also experimented briefly with Conduit but that didn't appear to provide any improvement.

ST forM_:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Control.Monad.ST.Trans as STT
import Control.Monad.Identity as Identity

testST :: Int
testST = do
  Identity.runIdentity $ STT.runST $ do
    a <- STT.newSTRef 0
    forM_ [1..10000000] (\x -> do
        a' <- STT.readSTRef a
        STT.writeSTRef a (a' + x)
      )
    STT.readSTRef a
```

Conduit:

```
import Data.Conduit (($=),(=$),($$))
import qualified Data.Conduit as C
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

testCL :: IO Int
testCL = CL.sourceList [1..10000000] $$ CL.foldM (\a x -> return (a + x)) 0
```

Comment: For performance tuning: it looks like `STT s Identity` will have some allocation overhead over the usual `ST s`; if you don't need the peculiar `STT` powers, you might want to just use `ST`.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed I may remove it, but I put it in the implementation initially expecting to need to embed `Either` and it got transferred over. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is not with the fold, but with the fold body. This program allocates a lot:

```
testST = runST $ do
    ref <- newSTRef 0
    forM_ [1..10000000] $ \x -> do
         val <- readSTRef ref
         writeSTRef ref (val + x)
    readSTRef ref
```

This program, whose only difference is on the `writeSTRef` line, allocates almost nothing:

```
testST = runST $ do
    ref <- newSTRef 0
    forM_ [1..10000000] $ \x -> do
        val <- readSTRef ref
        writeSTRef ref $! val + x
    readSTRef ref
```

The difference between the two pieces of code is a good hint to what's going on: in the former, you are creating a reference to a deeply-nested thunk with 10000000 layers of applications of `+`; whereas the latter flattens the thunk at each step.

By the way, this common pitfall is [explicitly called out in the documentation for `modifySTRef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-STRef.html#v:modifySTRef).

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I tried several strictness annotations and different fold methods but my focus was always on the arguments not the application. The thought that it was the write value never crossed my mind.

Comment: @ryachza Indeed, it is a subtle error, one that was burned into my brain by the despair of a late-night, last-minute debugging session...